# "envisager", "possibilité", or "éventuellement": Which of these three words requires the use of Subjonctif?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

> « On doit envisager la possibilité qu'éventuellement, elle n'***ait*** pas vu... »

I cannot figure out which of "envisager", "possibilité", or "éventuellement" necessitates Subjonctif in the ensuing clause.

Comment: I think the verb influences the use of subjunctive, so *envisager* would be the answer.

Comment: No, take this sentence for instance : "Il faut envisager des solutions stables et durables.". It is 'possibilité' indeed which implie the use of subjonctif.

Answer (score 2):

I would say *possibilité* because without it, I would use *qu'elle n'a pas vu*.

> On doit **envisager** la **possibilité** qu'elle n'ait pas vu...
>
> On doit **envisager** qu'**éventuellement**, elle n'a pas vu...
>
> On doit imaginer la **possibilité** qu'**éventuellement**, elle n'ait pas vu...

But I think subjonctif is not **required** in any case in this exemple, with or without *envisager*, *possibilité*, or *éventuellement*.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the subjonctif is used to denote a *possibility*. It is generally the meaning of the sentence that necessitates it, not a word in particular.
Here, "envisager", "possibilité", and "éventuellement" both means that what is following is only a possibility.

For example in the sentence

> Je serais triste qu'elle n'ait pas vu...

`Je serais triste` are not particular words, but the usage of conditional present denotes the same *possibility*, hence the subjonctif.